# Spring MVC: java.util.Optional MultipartFile[] @RequestParam argument is null in multipart/form-data POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Spring 4.1 introduced support for `java.util.Optional` in `@RequestParam` and `@RequestHeader` in controller method parameters.  I am using Spring 4.3.10.

If an `Optional` `@RequestParam` is not present in the request parameters, that value should be `Optional.EMPTY` as opposed to `null`.  However, an `Optional<MultipartFile[]>` parameter on a controller method handling a POSTed `multipart/form-data` request is NOT converting that parameter to `Optional.EMPTY` as expected but leaving it `null`.

Here's a quick demonstration of this issue:

```
<form action="<c:url value="/optionalPost"/>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

...

```
@PostMapping("/optionalPost")
public String postTest(@RequestParam Optional<MultipartFile[]> files) {
  System.out.println(files); // prints "null" -- not expected
  return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/optionalGet")
public String getTest(@RequestParam Optional<MultipartFile[]> files) {
  System.out.println(files); // prints "Optional.empty"
  return "index";
}
```

When the `Optional` type is something other than `MultipartFile[]`, it works as expected:

```
@PostMapping("/optionalPost")
public String postTest(@RequestParam Optional<String> name) {
  System.out.println(name); // prints "Optional.empty"
  return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/optionalGet")
public String getTest(@RequestParam Optional<String> name) {
  System.out.println(name); // prints "Optional.empty"
  return "index";
}
```

This will even work when the type is `MultipartFile` (and not `MultipartFile[]`):

```
@PostMapping("/optionalPost")
public String postTest(@RequestParam Optional<MultipartFile> file) {
  System.out.println(file); // prints "Optional.empty"
  return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/optionalGet")
public String getTest(@RequestParam Optional<MultipartFile> file) {
  System.out.println(file); // prints "Optional.empty"
  return "index";
}
```

Is this a known limitation? Is there any workaround to this other than to handle the possibility that this `Optional` argument may in fact be null?

Comment: It looks like you found a bug, but it's bad practice to use `Optional` for arrays or collections which is probably how it got missed. It's best to use array/collection emptiness as a sign that there is no data rather than wrapping them in an optional.

Comment: Issue created: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15918

Comment: Fix should be present in 4.3.12 and 5.0 GA.  See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/15c82afc1cdedc95b453e8f4ca61fd72f4a3ae82